# Calculating average of students' scores (with different coefficients)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, average

I have to calculate the average of students scores.

Students have two different scores: midterm, and final.

```
first course average = ( (midterm score*1) + (Final score*2) ) / 3 )
```

How can do this by ASP.NET (C#) and SQL?

This confuses me. Which part should be written with C# or SQL?

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what flavor of SQL
You can do this all in SQL by simply creating a new column 'first course average'.  Assuming you have a table with one record per student

```
SELECT ([Midterm Score] + (2 * [Final Score])) / 3 AS 'first course average'
FROM #gradeTable 
GROUP BY [Student ID]
```

You could alternatively use the LINQ library in C#, but given the simplicity of this exercise, that really isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The scores will all be stored in a sql database.  you can also do the calculations in Sql using specialized queries.  In this case it may be easiest to just retrieve the scores and do the calculations in c# (or any other programming language) I like python and php, but everything ahs it's place.

Does that answer your question.

Comment: how can i calcute this formula by sql?! i mean first i have to SUM(GradeColumns) oh before that have to do: Grade*ItsCoefficient , should i save these valuse in MyDb?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct calculate from SQL like this:

```
SELECT ((Midterm + (Final*2))/3) AS First_Course_Average FROM Scores WHERE ...
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163fc/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that also by writing it in the formula section. which can be found in column properties .